# How to fix missing php extensions problems in custom Docker image?

Tags: 8, installation

There are many excellent questions here about automating the initial setup process for Drupal but I haven't seen any pertaining specifically to Drupal containers in Docker.

Here's my setup. I've kept the images/builds as vanilla as possible; the only Dockerfile I have is for `composer`, inspired by the [accepted answer to this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258739/automate-drupal-8-installation-with-composer).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

  drupal:
    image: drupal
    ports:
      - 8888:80

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal8
       MYSQL_USER: drupal8
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal8
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: drupal8
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - drupal

  drush:
    image: drush/drush

  composer:
    image: composer
    build: composer_init
    depends_on:
      - drupal
      - drush
```

Dockerfile for `composer`:

```
FROM composer

RUN composer -vvv create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project /var/www/html --stability dev --no-interaction
RUN cd /var/www/html
RUN drush si -y \
  --db-url=mysql://root:drupal8@localhost/drupal8 \
  --site-name=drupal8 \
  --site-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
  --account-mail=drupal8@foo.com \
  --account-name=drupal8 \
  --account-pass=drupal8 >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I spun up the build process by issuing `docker-compose up -d --build`.
Now when the process reached the composer part, it blew up with the following message:

```
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core 8.5.x-dev requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - drupal/core 8.5.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for drupal/core ~8.5.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.5.1, 8.5.x-dev].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - 
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/date_timezone.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Based on other answers/suggestions here, I added a Dockerfile to my drupal section and added `RUN apt-get install php7.0-gd` to the Dockerfile, but this now blows up with `E: Package 'php7.0-gd' has no installation candidate`.

I've ensured that the PHP version for this Docker image is PHP 7.

`php --ini` gives me:

```
# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
```

How can I resolve this error now?

Comment: Someone already automated everything, don't reinvent the wheel, use [https://www.kalabox.io/](https://www.kalabox.io/) saves time & unnecessary headaches.

Comment: Try `apt-get install php-gd`. After it installs you need to ensure that extension is loaded in the relevant files.

Comment: @NoSssweat - I'm trying to stick to using only native Docker solutions without external tools

Comment: @Kevin `apt-get install php-gd` gives `Unable to locate package php-gd` too

Comment: Are you doing `RUN apt-get update` before doing any installs?

Comment: @Kevin yes i am.

Comment: Can you provide all the related files you are using here? I don't see all the commands mentioned in the comments in the examples you provided. And most importantly, your question sounds more like "How to fix missing php extensions problems in custom Docker image for Drupal 8?". Please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the `drush` and `composer` services from the docker-compose file and updating my Dockerfile for drupal as follows:

```
FROM drupal


RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y wget vim git mysql-client

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
    chmod +x drush.phar && \
    mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much more easy to install composer in your Drupal-Dockerfile and install Drupal, drush and console from that composer.

You could extend my Dockerfile here https://hub.docker.com/r/feikede/drupal8-docker/ with a "drush si" and your done.